# How to override OnItemSelected method in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to override the ***OnItemSelected*** method of a **Spinner** in my **Fragment**, the same way I did with ***OnClick*** on **Button**, but it's not responding anymore

Inside the OnCreate, the commented block works perfectly, but I want to clean it because I have more than one spinner in this layout and this way it is getting very polluted.

**Another question:** If possible , how this ***OnNothingSelected*** method works and how to use it more effectively?

In the expression "if (itemSelected! =" ... ")" is because the first element of my spinner is a string with "....", so as not to have any item selected at the beginning, I'm using this wonderfull technique... How could I improve this?

My code is as follows:

***Vetarano2.kt***

```
com.mtsa.escudeiro_rpghelper.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.Toast
import com.mtsa.escudeiro_rpghelper.R

class Veterano2 : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private lateinit var spinner: Spinner
    private lateinit var button: Button

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_veterano2, container, false)


        initViews(fragView)
        initListeners()

        // SPINNER RAÇA
        /*
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val selecionado = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
                Toast.makeText(context, "Opção escolhida: $selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }
        */

        return fragView
    }

    private fun initViews(v: View) {
        spinner = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner2)
        button = v.findViewById(R.id.button2)
    }

    private fun initListeners() {
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = this
        button.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        when (view?.id) {
            R.id.spinner2 -> {
                val selecionado = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
                Toast.makeText(context, "Opção escolhida: $selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.button2 -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "SALVAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***fragment_veterano2.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="64dp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/array_example"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

***arrays_diversos.xml***

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="array_example">
        <item>AAAAA</item>
        <item>BBBBB</item>
        <item>CCCCC</item>
        <item>DDDDD</item>
        <item>EEEEE</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: Reformatted code for better visualization, but the problem persists

Comment: Inside `onItemSelected()` you try match `R.id.spinner`, but the id of your spinner is `R.id.fragVet2_spnRaca` - that is the problem

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, this code here was just an example of what I have, the original is a little big to paste here. I'll edit my question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener#onItemSelected(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)) says, if you have multiple spinners, you should judge the id of `parent` like below, sorry,I just know java.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int iid = parent.getId();
        switch (iid) {
            case R.id.spinner1:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hello,spinner1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.spinner2:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hello,spinner2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            break; 
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I did not find where it says this, but judging by the logic I should have taken before, I think I need more hours of sleep ... kkk
Thank you friend!